# jQuery lightslider plugin pager onclick event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I want to get the onclick event of jquery lightslider plugin's pager element, I tried the following code,

```
var $slide = $('#light-slider').parent('.lSSlideWrapper');
var $cSouter = $slide.parent();
var $pager = $cSouter.find('.lSPager').find('li').find('a');            
console.log($pager);
$pager.on('click',function(){
    console.log('test');                
});
```

the console.log of `pager` prints the following value

```
[a, a, a, a, prevObject: n.fn.init[4], context: document, selector: ".lSPager li a"]
```

but the link onclick event not firing, may I know what wrong I did.

Comment: Does it have to be when the buttons are clicked, or will it suffice to act when the slide changes to next or previous?

Comment: actually, the slide pausing when click on pager, but I want to play it after 10 secs

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure I follow. Can you make a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: see this link http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html

Comment: Ok, can you explain what you would like it to do in more detail?

Comment: when user click on the bottom pager the slides pausing, that is fine, but I want to play it automatically after 10 secs

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest issue is that the function that is bound to the pager controls by the plugin ends with `return false;` which prevents any further bubbling for this event so no other functions that are bound to the element after this are going to get called.

```
$pager.on('click', function() {
  if (settings.loop === true && settings.mode === 'slide') {
    scene = scene + ($pager.index(this) -

      $cSouter.find('.lSPager').find('li.active').index());
  } else {
    scene = $pager.index(this);
  }
  $el.mode(false);
  if (settings.gallery === true) {
    $this.slideThumb();
  }
  clearInterval(interval);
  return false; // this line prevents any further bubbling for this event so not other functions that are bound to the element after this are going to get called
});
```

---

The cleanest way around this, IMHO, would be to modify the plugin to add a callback function like `onBeforePageChange` which will allow you to do something like this:

```
$('#responsive').lightSlider({
        item:4,
        loop:false,
        slideMove:2,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)',
        speed:600,
        responsive : [
            {
                breakpoint:800,
                settings: {
                    item:3,
                    slideMove:1,
                    slideMargin:6,
                  }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:480,
                settings: {
                    item:2,
                    slideMove:1
                  }
            }
        ],
        onBeforePageChange: function () { // this is a custom callback we have added
            console.log('onBeforePrevSlide called'); // do what ever you want here, like play the slider after a delay
        }
    });
```

#### Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/2patspw2/1356/) with the callback added into the plugin code